# How to change the text caret color in Eclipse?

Tags: linux, eclipse, user-interface, cursor

I'm using a light-background color scheme in Eclipse on Linux (Arch Linux) and the text caret with this scheme in Eclipse is black. I want to set a custom color for the text caret. It seems there is no in Eclipse (Luna) any configuration settings related to the text caret. I tried to change the caret color systemwide in the ~/.gtkrc-2.0 file and also tried to configure GTK settings specifically for Eclipse in the .gtkrc file in the Eclipse directory:

```
style "custom" {
GtkWidget::cursor-color="#288C28"
GtkWidget::secondary-cursor-color="#288C28"
}

widget_class "*" style "custom"
```

The text caret color has actually changed, but only in dialog editor windows. In code editors for all languages including plain text - the text caret remains black. Changing the color theme - doesn't help. Is there any way to control the text caret appearance in the code editors in Eclipse?

Comment: Do you have **Use custom caret** checked in **General** > **Editors** > **Text Editors** > **Accessibility**?

Comment: Yes, I tried several combinations of checked flags on the Accessibility tab, none changes the caret color.